# Showing ImportError: cannot import name 'Message' from 'can'

Tags: python, linux, python-import, python-can

I am importing CAN messages in `Python` and I am using `python-can` library. So the line in my python code here is:

```
from can import Message
```

It was working fine but after I changed the folders, I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rafi/PycharmProjects/Right Turn/CAN_simulator_Recv.py", line 12, in <module>
    from can import Message
ImportError: cannot import name 'Message' from 'can' (/home/rafi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/can/__init__.py)
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Maybe it has something to do with directory or packages? The same `can` library is working fine in other linux machines. I tried uninstalling `python-can` but it doesn't work.
Please help.

Comment: "It was working fine but after I changed the folders". What changes did you do ?

Answer (score 0):

It's some kind of import bug. Try import Message like this:

```
from can.message import Message
```

Everything worked for me.